# Using template tags inside of Javascript with Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, api, google-maps

I'm making an IP address tracker with `Django`, I'm using the **Google Maps API** to create the map and for geolocation [this API](https://ip-api.com/docs/api:json), I want it to show my location on the map automatically when I open the page, and if it is another IP address, then the location on the map of that IP address,

The problem is that **I don't know how to integrate the `Django` code into** `Javascript` for the coordinates, or I don't know if there is another way to make it easier, or with other APIs.

In the Javascript file in the **coord** variable I want to pass the parameters of the json **lat** and **longit** for the **lat** and **lng** of Javascript to take it.

Files:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
import requests

def get_ip_tracker(request):
    response = requests.get('http://ip-api.com/json/')
    geodata = response.json()
    data= {
            'ip': geodata['query'],
            'country': geodata['country'],
            'timezone':geodata['timezone'],
            'lat': geodata['lat'],
            'longit': geodata['lon'],
            'isp':geodata['isp'],
            'api_key':'My api key',
        }

    return render(request, 'geolocationip/home.html', data)
```

script.js:

```
    function initMap(){
       //var lat="{{ lat }}";
       //var lng="{{ longit }}";       
       var coord = {lat: ?, lng: ?};
       console.log(coord) 
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
          zoom: 10,
          center: coord
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: coord,
          map: map
        });
      }
```

home.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
    
{% block content %}
<h1 id="ip">IP Address Tracker</h1>

<form method="get"id="form">
    <input><button>Search</button>
</form>

  <div id="card">
    <p>Your ip address is <strong>{{ ip }}</strong>, and you are probably in <strong>{{ country }}</strong> right now, and 
    <strong>{{timezone}}</strong> and <strong>{{isp}}</strong></p>
  </div>  

<div id="map"></div>
{% endblock content %}


{% block js %}

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{ api_key }}&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"defer></script>

{% endblock js %}
```

My app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbo0M.png